# How to run a function in another python script with arguments?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a script that runs another python script with a few different commands. I want to authenticate a user and search a song given by the user. Then the script authenticates  the spotify account, searches for the given song and then plays it.

Here's how it looks when to authenticate Respotify the moment:

```
python respotify.py john doe
```

Searching for a song:

```
search Wrecking Ball
```

Play a song after a specified number of search The results will be:

```
play 1
```

I know what I could call the function using this for example in my play.py file:

```
import os
os.system = ("search Wrecking Ball")
```

But I want my "play.py" to run the respotify.py in the background. I've tried with putting this inside a respotify.py function so that maybe a song could be called as the script starts.

```
import os 

os.system = "search Wrecking Ball"
```

I tried but my script would just ignore it.

But I think that it's more complicated than that. You can find respotify.py [here](https://github.com/Hexxeh/spotify-websocket-api/blob/master/clients/respotify/respotify.py):

Close on solving my problem now thanks to [nickie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1653187/nickie)

His answer was:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(["python", "respotify.py", "john", "doe"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
print >> p.stdin, "search Wrecking Ball"
output = p.communicate()[0]
```

But I got this error in my console:

```
File "respotify.py", line 338, in <module> command_loop() File "respotify.py", line 29, in command_loop command = raw_input().split(" ") EOFError: EOF when reading line
```

How do I fix this error above?

Comment: Are you trying to interact with the other script, sending commands and then waiting for prompts and responses? If so, check out [`pexpect`](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect). But I don't think you need to do this in the first place…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `os.system` and `subprocess.call` execute a program in a subprocess, as if from the command line.  If I understand right, you want to execute the command:

```
python respotify.py john doe
```

and feed it with input, as if given to its `stdin`, that will contain the line:

```
search Wrecking Ball
```

This can be done with the following code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(["python", "respotify.py", "john", "doe"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
input = "search Wrecking Ball\n" + "play 1\n"
output = p.communicate(input)[0]
```

or, if the input that you want to provide depends on the output that the subprocess is giving you, you could print to `p.stdin` and read from `p.stdout`.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(["python", "respotify.py", "john", "doe"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
print >> p.stdin, "search Wrecking Ball"
output = p.stdout.readline()
print >> p.stdin, "play 1"
print >> p.stdin, "quit"
p.wait()
```

Check the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) of the `subprocess` module for further details.

If the communication protocol with your subprocess is complicated, you should absolutely use something better than this, like the [`pexpect`](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect) library that @abernert suggested.

Comment: Looks great, just got some errors returned though. I'll share them:
`File "respotify.py", line 338, in <module>
    command_loop()
File "respotify.py", line 29, in command_loop
    command = raw_input().split(" ")
EOFError: EOF when reading line`

Comment: import sys
Will now try to make some sound in my speakers.

Comment: You really shouldn't write to `stdin` directly if you're going to use `communicate`. Just pass `"search Wrecking Ball"` as the `input` to the function. But it sounds like this isn't going to work anyway, so…

Comment: @Jack: You might be able to get past that error just by adding another newline or something. But really, it looks like respotify is not designed to be scripted, and you're going to need to fake a complete interactive session, so this is going to be a dead end.

Comment: @nickie:It worked so far, I've read a bit in the documentation but can't find how to send in the command "play 1" after executing the "search Wrecking Ball". How could I solve this?

Comment: Getting an error, and not being able to send a second command, counts as "working fine"? This isn't "a bad solution"—it's a great way to drive scriptable apps. But if respotify is not scriptable, it's not the _right_ solution.

Comment: Just print as many commands you want to the `p.stdin`.  I included one more in the answer.  Obviously @abarnert is right, you should not use `communicate` if printing to the `stdin`.  I'm changing my answer to contain both options.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to interact with a CLI script—send commands, wait for responses and prompts, etc.—is a pain in the neck. There are libraries like [`pexpect`](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect) that make it easier for you, but it's still not easy.

---

But fortunately, you don't have to. `respotify` is clearly usable as a module instead of a script, so, rather than try to generate input to feed it so it can parse it, and so on, just import it and use it directly.

Or, even more simply, all of the code in `respotify` is simple—at least as simple as trying to interact with it over a CLI. So just use the Spotify modules directly.

Answer (score 2):

```
os.system = ("search Wrecking Ball")
```

Doesn't do what you think it does. You want

```
output = os.system("search Wrecking Ball")
```

Note that the modern way to do this is

```
output = subprocess.call(["search", "Wrecking", "Ball"])
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you think this is going to fix. `output` in either case is just going to be a number—whatever the other script's exit code was—that his code doesn't seem to have any use for. Neither change is going to make it work if it's not working, or make it run in the background (as he implied he wanted at one point), or give him a chance to pass in input, or anything else.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. Nvm then.

Answer (score 1):

If you can possibly avoid it, PLEASE do not make your Python scripts run other Python scripts via subprocess or via pexec, et.al.  These are last-ditch options "from an Older Age".

Python gives us the **wonderful** gift of just `import`ing another Python script as a library and calling it directly.

If you possibly can, `import respotify` and call its methods directly.  If not, "library-itize" it so that it can be called directly.  Your time and sanity will thank you for it.